# What kind of pipes specifically do we need to get for a double basin kitchen sink?

Tags: plumbing, sink

We just got a fixer upper and the house had been vacant so long somebody took all the plumbing pipes to the sinks inside the house.. the pipes under the house from the well and to the septic tank seem to be Intact, but I have no idea what we need to connect the sink to the water supply and drainage..

Comment: Do you mean to say  that there is no water supply pipes  ( in the walls ) from the water heater and the the line from the well **TO** the rooms with fixtures, I.E. kitchen, bathroom, laundry. Or just lines from the pipes/valves in the walls to the sink itself ?  They took drain plumbing as well?   We need more details.

Answer (score -1):

There is a kit you can get at most big box home improvement shops, but you need the drains themselves (if you don't already have them) to go through the bottom of the sink, then you'll have pipe coming down and either connecting in the middle (sort of a T shape) or the pipe from one side will come across and dump into the other.  If you have a dishwasher, this is about where you should expect to attach it's drain line.  Continuing on, you will then have either a P trap (if the drain goes through the wall) or an S trap (if the drain line is to go through the floor).

For supply, the big question comes down to how many holes there are for the spigot.  Count the holes, then pick out a fixture you like that uses that many holes.  Get 2 adapters while you're at it to go from whatever connection the fixture uses to your supply pipe (probably 1/2", possibly 3/4").  If there will be a dishwasher, the hot water often gets teed off for it in that general vicinity.  Just upstream, put shutoff valves on both the hot and cold water lines coming in.

Comment: Please share a picture of what you see under the sink and explain whether you have a 1, 2 or 3 bowl kitchen sink. A close-up of the drain fitting at the wall would be helpful to better show drain location relative to the sink drain, drain pipe type and maybe size.

We also need to know if there will be a disposal and/or a dishwasher on the right side?

I believe S traps are no longer allowed.  Under sink kits don't include adapters to connect to the drain and don't cover all situations. 

With the above information, I can suggest EXACTLY what to buy and how to plumb.

Comment: And show a picture of the supply lines attached to the faucet. Contrary to @poorplanning, they will be either female 1/2 " pipe thread, 1/2" compression or, most likely, 3/8" compression. Your new supply valves will have to match what the faucet has. Or, if you have existing supply valves, include a close picture of those too.